# PostgreSQL and hibernate - Function rownumber() doesn't exist

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am currently trying to use Hibernate generated functions for a PostgreSQL Database. It all works correctly except for when I use the functions setFirstResult() and setMaxResults() on my hibernate queries.

Here is a sample of my Java code :

```
String queryString = "select h from History h " ;
Query onePageQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString)
                .setFirstResult(rowMin).setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE);
onePageQuery.getResultList();
```

The generated query is the following :

```
select
    * 
from
( select
    rownumber() over(
order by
    history0_.DTMTC desc) as rownumber_,
    history0_.ID as ID2_,
    history0_.CCOUL as CCOUL2_,
    history0_.CDIAM as CDIAM2_,
    history0_.CODAV as CODAV2_,
    history0_.COOPVM as COOPVM2_,
    history0_.COOPVT as COOPVT2_,
    history0_.CPOTA as CPOTA2_,
    history0_.DTMTC as DTMTC2_,
    history0_.TYCOUP as TYCOUP2_ 
from
    F23VCM2D history0_ 
order by
    history0_.DTMTC desc ) as temp_ 
where
    rownumber_ <= ?
```

Before I used a PostgreSQL database, I was using a DB2 Database. I have a `jpa.xml` file in which I declare that I am using a POSTGRESQL database as follows :

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
    <!-- <property name="database" value="DB2" /> -->
  </bean>
</property>
```

I think that maybe the generated query is not adapted to PostgreSQL, because the error I have is : (roughly translated from French)

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the function rownumber() Doesn't exist
  Hint : There's no function corresponding to the given name or the arguments types.
You need to add explicit type conversion.
```

My questions are :

1) Is the generated query the one that should be generated ? I doubt it cause I tried to send it via SQL Developper and it failed.

2) Is there something that is obvious I didn't do with my hibernate set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my side : there were two `jpa.xml` files. 
I didn't know this because it's a legacy project where I'm trying to change only the database connection. Hence, I was trying to modify the wrong `jpa.xml` file so there were no impact on the generated queries.

Once I had removed the "DB2" line :

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="DB2" />
  </bean>
</property>
```

and replaced it with the "POSTGRE" line, in the right file, it worked and the query was generated successfully. So the following version of the jpaVendorAdapter did it for me :

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
  </bean>
</property>
```

Thank you for the other input, it helped me find the answer. There didn't seem to need to add the dialect part, so I didn't add it in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Modify `jpaVendorAdapter` like this :

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
     <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
  </bean>
</property>
```

in order to correctly set the hibernate dialect.

Comment: That should be `PostgreSQL95Dialect` not the outdated 8.2 version

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Whatever, the idea is to set the dialect.